# How to add flash object into custom task pane of Outlook using VSTO?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-addin, outlook-2007-addin

Can you please let me know how to add flash object into the custom task pane using VSTO?

Comment: please mark the answer as answered, since it seems like you benefited from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "Shockwave flash object" control to your task pane or form region.
You may have to find it in your user controls and add it in you tool box. 
You can then set the Movie property to the URI of the flash swf.

Marcus

**Update**

You can add you swf file to your project and set it to copy to output
then you need to reference it in code.

add a helper property to you addin or copy the code out.

```
 static public string AssemblyDirectory { 
            get { 
                string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase; 
                UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase); 
                string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path); 
                return Path.GetDirectoryName(path); 
            } 
        }
```

Then in your taskpane showing/init event

```
String swfPath = AssemblyDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "menu.swf";
axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, swfPath);
```

Comment: yes i did that but when i do setup the pulgin it will not have the  flash object in it that is i tried to place the .swf (flash file) in project bin folder it didnt work but if i place flash file ouside the project folder and specify the path then it works fine even in that during setup .swf files are not copied

Comment: please help me how can i slove this

Comment: like in VB.NET when we are adding flash object into windows forms then we would save the .swf file in bin folder of the project and include the .swf file path like this :-flashobj.Movie=Application.StartupPath & "\movie.swf"
like then when project set up is done it would include .swf files defaultly from taht path , but in VSTO its not working like taht since its exceute path is different we cant use Application.StartupPath to include the .swf file defaulty

Comment: please can i know to which folder of my project i must add .swf file

Comment: hi Marcus  thanks for the post 
i tried as u specified i placed .swf file in project folder i.e in bin directory then i copied that into output directory and i added ur code but it works when it is executed but it will not work when application is run through setup please can i know how to make it work

Comment: divya, How are you seting this up as click once ? also can you see the swf file in you vsto cache folder ? it could be a number of things .. one that it not getting copied or 2 security is stopping it .. also ouput the path ... Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase should get you the manifest .

Comment: You could also install the swf file in a known path on the client may be %app_data%

Comment: ya i am trying to setup through click once .swf file is available in setup folder Application files>bin>debug but also its not taking no security issue 
but one more thing i s after deployment the file extension is getting change like i.e before deployment movie.swf and after deployemnet movie.swf.DEPLOY like this its changing i am not able to proceed
really can be place flash object in custom pane???

Comment: How shall i copy .swf file in the process of setup ?? and how shall install swf file through setup??

Comment: Clickonce is a pain... when you click the vsto file its insatlls the addin into another location .. normally on XP c:\document and settings\<username>\Local Settings\Apps\2.0 and normally under one of the sub dires there. take a look to see if you swf flie is bein installed into there. You could always do a good old msi install .. check out : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSTO3MSI/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=729

Comment: yes it getting copyied to the c:\document and settings\<username>\Local Settings\Apps\2.0 \flashexmp\bin\movie.swf to this location  so can i give the path for this ,if yes then how can i give please help me

Comment: .swf is getting copied to the c:\document and settings\<username>\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\99876512.. \flashexmp..\bin\movie.swf to this location so can i give the path for this ,if yes then how can i give please help me